# Review audit for deleted non-answer passed by simply expanding comments on the question

Tags: bug, review-audits

While reviewing [this review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/1438580), I was curious to see what the comments on the question were, as it said "show **6** more comments" with none currently showing.

When doing that, I passed a review-audit. That feels fantastic and such, and definitely works against robo-reviewers (who'd never click anything but "Looks Good Kthnx Bai!") but I'm wondering if this really is intended behaviour, especially as I'm greeted with this message:

> This **answer** has already been removed, **but thanks for considering leaving feedback for its author.**

I clicked the comments-expando-link for the **question**. Not the answer.

> [image: review-audit-success-get]

Comment: Hum. The image in there makes the formatting of the question look messy. Should I just remove it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm willing to bet that this is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign).

You expanded the comments. That means you were paying attention.

(Or rather, you did ***something*** to take a closer look.)

Comment: Yeah, that was pretty much my comment about the robo-reviewers in there, so I'm inclined to agree... but you never now. It could also be [status-byaccident] ;)

Comment: Or it could be both: It wasn't designed that way. But it turns out to be unintended desirable behavior.

Comment: Naturally. Best kind of "bug". =)

Comment: Yeah, there are a *ton* of different ways to figure out that these are audits. Of course, you have to be willing to pay attention in order to do so, which the folks they're aimed at generally don't. That said, we may need to make these harder at some point as folks become accustom to them.

Comment: Since no other answer has been provided, I'll take this highly educated guess as suitable enough. =)